# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'value_index' and 'dtype'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
tf.Tensor([3,2])
```

when I do this I got the error with

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'value_index' and 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.constant([3,2])` instead of `tf.Tensor([3,2])`